# Syntax error on PDO query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I wrote an update function that is available inside a wrapper, actually the function looks like this:

```
public function update($table, $data, $where, $fields)
{
    $params = [];
    $fieldDetails = NULL;

    foreach($data as $key => $value)
    {
        $fieldDetails .= "`$key`=:$key,";
        $params[$key] = $fields[$key];
    }

    var_dump('UPDATE ' . $table . ' SET ' . $fieldDetails . 'WHERE' . $where);

    return $this->prepare("UPDATE $table SET $fieldDetails WHERE $where")
        ->execute($params);
}
```

As you can see I pass the name of the table where I need to update the value, the data to update, the where clause and the relative fields of where clause.
I'm executing it this way:

```
try {
        $this->db->update('auth_tokens', $auth, 'user_id = :user_id',
            [':user_id' => $auth['user_id']]);
    }catch (Exception $e)
    {
        var_dump($e);
    }
```

the problem's that I get this message:

> object(PDOException)#15 (8) { ["message":protected]=> string(222) "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE user_id = NULL' at line 1"

seems that the :user_id in where clause is considered null. What is wrong in my code?

Comment: What's in the variable `$auth['user_id']` right before you execute the query?

Comment: there is the id of the logged user, the value is 1

Comment: user id is null.... print `$auth['user_id']` on top

Comment: So, what exactly *is* the final query you've cobbled together? What does the `var_dump` show?

Comment: @deceze the var_dump inside the update function print: UPDATE auth_tokens SET `selector`=:selector,`token`=:token,`expires`=:expires,`user_id`=:user_id,WHEREuser_id = :user_id

Comment: Yeah, pretty obvious syntax problem, no?

Comment: you're right I forgot to unset user_id in the auth array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :)

This line of code is causing problem:

```
$fieldDetails .= "`$key`=:$key,";
```

Here you are adding a comma(,) after every column and the final string you will get extra trailing comma(,) remove that and all set.

So add this after the loop:

```
$fieldDetails = rtrim($fieldDetails, ',');
```

Comment: just a thing: if I unset in auth user_id I get: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Comment: Why you are doing that? Error message explaining the error;

Comment: I don't think you need to unset user_id unless you pass it in 2nd parameter $data.  If you still have doubts share values you are passing to function update()

Answer (score 1):

```
$fieldDetails .= "`$key`=:$key,";
                              ^
```

You will always have a trailing comma here, resulting in:

```
..., WHERE
```

You should put the individual fields into an array, then `implode` that, which will put the commas into the right places.

Answer (score 0):

When your `$data` is empty than you do not execute loop and `$fieldDetails` stays null, that causes syntax error.

Comment: The code enter in the loop and all the arrays passed are fill correctly, anyway, I print user_id and the code display: 1, so no idea why I get this error